# type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get the details by id (this is from tmdb)

```
  Stream<DetailsTv> getDetailsTv(int id) async* {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get('$mainUrl/tv/$id?api_key=$apiKey&language=en-US');
    yield DetailsTv.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }
```

```
StreamBuilder<DetailsTv>(
          stream: stream.getDetailsTv(id),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Container(
                child: Text(snapshot.data.name),
              );
            }
            else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                    );
                  } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          }),
```

but i got this error
type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'
but the id is int

Comment: Check the datatype of id you are passing to `stream: stream.getDetailsTv(id)`

Answer (score 0):

`stream.getDetailsTv(int.parse(id.toString()))`
to ensure converting id to int

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.